# SpringBoot request mapping error catching

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-boot, exception

I have a method mapping like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/toto_list/{toto_name}/tata_list", "/toto_list/{toto_name}/tata_list/{tata_name}"}, produces = {"application/json", "text/json"})
    public ReturnType myMethod(@PathVariable("toto_name") final String _totoName, @PathVariable(value = "tata_name") Optional<String> _tata_name, final HttpServletRequest _request) throws JAXBException, DatatypeConfigurationException, FrontendException, ServletException { 
...
}
```

I would like to catch an eventually error mapping to response BAD_REQUEST. How could i do?

When I request my spring boot application with

> "http://[IP]:[PORT]/AppName/toto_list/toto1/tata_listERROR"

I've got an http error 406 NOT_FOUND.

Log application: [WARN ] [o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AppName/toto_list/toto1/tata_listERROR] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

How could I catch this exception to response BAD_REQUEST and no NOT_FOUND?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your clients start with /toto_list then you can write another RequestMapping like so to throw 404 which did not fall into any other mapping in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/toto_list")
public class MyController() {

/**
    catch every url other than /toto_list/hello and /toto_list/bye and return 404
*/
@RequestMapping(value="**",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public void didNotMatchAnything(){
  throw new ResourceNotFoundException(); ;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void hello(){
  //do something
}

@RequestMapping(value="/bye",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void bye(){
  //do something
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks  @Jayesh, It runs :-)

Comment: updated my answer to explain in detail. I'm glad it worked. enjoy!